# Radiobutton does'nt react on first click in my windows forms application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows forms application that contains three different groupboxes with at least seven radiobuttons in each groupbox, one listbox (that shows the text from the checked radiobutton and one button that will send away the text from the checkboxes into a database. Everything works fine but my radiobuttons.

My problem is that you have to click on the radiobutton twice for it to be displayed in my listbox and later on sent away into my database, and I don't understand why?

In my code I have three empty variables:

```
    string flowerValueRadioButton = string.Empty;
    string fruitValueRadioButton = string.Empty;
    string candyValueRadioButton = string.Empty;
```

And I declare each of the variables in a foreach loop, like this :

```
private void candyGroupBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (RadioButton candyRadioButton in candyGroupBox.Controls)
        {

            if (candyRadioButton.Checked == true)
            {
                receiptListBox.Items.Add(candyRadioButton.Text);
                candyValueRadioButton = candyRadioButton.Text;
            }

            if (candyRadioButton.Checked == false)
            {
                receiptListBox.Items.Remove(candyRadioButton.Text);
            }
        }
    }
```

What do I need to do for my radiobutton value to get in to my database and listbox on the first click?
Thank you

Comment: Where do you initialise your radio buttons and handle the click event?

Comment: Your code is in the `GroupBox_Enter()` event. Move the code into the `CheckChanged()` event for the `RadioButton`. When you click on the `RadioButton` in the `GroupBox`, the `GroupBox_Enter()` event fires. When it checks if candyRadioButton is checked, it returns `false` because the `candyRadioButton` hasn't been checked yet. The check state changes after the `GroupBox_Enter` event. When you click the second time, the `candyRadioButton` is already checked, so you get the behavior you want. Moving the code to the `RadioButton.CheckChanged` event should solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do I have do this on every individual button? Or is it possible to implement this in somekind of loop? I have a lot of radiobuttons so there will be a lot of "repeated code" if I do this on every single radiobutton.

Comment: @Frodo Every radio button will need a `RadioButton_Click()` event handler. However, you can make it the same handler for all buttons. The first option would be getting the control name from the `sender` by casting it to a `RadioButton`. Determine what to add to your list by the name of the control. The second is to put the string value for each `RadioButton` in the control's `Tag`. Then, you can get the value doing something like this: `string value = ((RadioButton)sender).Tag.ToString();`